# How to get playlist by name in android default music player?

Tags: java, android

I want to play songs of a playlist name "myPlaylist" from Android music player in my Application i searched on internet that plays songs of selected playlist we can select playlist by ID i have 3 playlists in my GenyMotion i pass

```
  PlaySongsFromAPlaylist(0);
```

the 0 for first playlist
my method is

```
    public void PlaySongsFromAPlaylist(int playListID){

    String[] ARG_STRING = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

    Uri membersUri= MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playListID);
    Cursor songsWithingAPlayList = this.managedQuery(membersUri, ARG_STRING, null, null, null);
    int theSongIDIwantToPlay = 0; // PLAYING FROM THE FIRST SONG
    if(songsWithingAPlayList != null)
    {
        songsWithingAPlayList.moveToPosition(theSongIDIwantToPlay);
        String DataStream = songsWithingAPlayList.getString(4);
        PlayMusic(DataStream);
        songsWithingAPlayList.close();
    }   
}
```

but i am geting error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xample.playfromplaylist/com.xample.playfromplaylist.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

what is the problem can anyone help?

Comment: songsWithingAPlayList is empty.

Comment: but i have songs in my playlist how it can be empty?

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).